# Wager calculation for the thirder position (Sleeping Beauty problem)

Tags: logic, epistemology

Here is the problem for those unfamiliar with it:

> Sleeping Beauty volunteers to undergo the following experiment and is told all of the following details: On Sunday she will be put to sleep. Once or twice, during the experiment, Sleeping Beauty will be awakened, interviewed, and put back to sleep with an amnesia-inducing drug that makes her forget that awakening. A fair coin will be tossed to determine which experimental procedure to undertake:

> If the coin comes up heads, Sleeping Beauty will be awakened and interviewed on Monday only.

> If the coin comes up tails, she will be awakened and interviewed on Monday and Tuesday.

> In either case, she will be awakened on Wednesday without interview and the experiment ends.

> Any time Sleeping Beauty is awakened and interviewed she will not be able to tell which day it is or whether she has been awakened before. During the interview Sleeping Beauty is asked: "What is your credence now for the proposition that the coin landed heads?"

Now I understand what the thirder position is and how they arrived there and I still think it is wrong. Though in my quest to understand the reasoning [they came up with an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem#Thirder_position):

> An alternative argument is as follows: Credence can be viewed as the amount a rational risk-neutral bettor would wager if the payoff for being correct is 1 unit (the wager itself being lost either way). In the heads scenario, Sleeping Beauty would spend her wager amount one time, and receive 1 money for being correct. In the tails scenario, she would spend her wager amount twice, and receive nothing. Her expected value is therefore to gain 0.5 but also lose 1.5 times her wager, thus she should break even if her wager is 1/3.

And quite frankly I don't understand how they ended up with 0.5 gain and 1.5 loss. Like what are they doing and why?

Like if she were to place a bet each time and lose a token for being incorrect and gain one for being correct, then there are 4 possible scenarios:

- She believes it's heads and it is heads. So she places one bet and wins 1 tokens.
- She believes it's heads but it is tails. She gambles 2 times and loses 2 tokens.
- She believes it's tails and it is tails. She gambles 2 times and wins 2 tokens.
- She believes it's tails but it is heads. She gambles 1 time and loses 1 token.

This is under the assumption that she always places the same bet because there's no rational reason why her credence should change over the course of the experiment. In case her credence is just random like a coin flip. Well that's essentially 1 coin flip of what she believes for heads and 2 for tails.

- So for heads is lose 1 token or win 1 token
- And for tails it's lose 25% lose 2 tokens, 50% win one lose one = gain 0 tokens, 25% win 2 tokens.

So there would be a difference between the outcomes of the two examples. Like in the steady guessing case it's:

- She believes it's heads 50% * 1 + 50% * -2 = -0.5 on average
- She believes it's tails 50% *2 + 50% *-1 = 0.5 on average

While in the random credence they are technically both just coin flips with an expected value of 0 but if you were to be loss avoidant then the tails case has a 75% to avoid losses and the heads case has only a 50% chance. But in either case that is not your choice to make so it doesn't matter.

However none of that yields a 0.5 gain and 1.5 loss. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how they ended up with 0.5 gain and 1.5 loss. Like
> what are they doing and why?

Well, they are not using ratios consistently, and "in the Heads scenario" means what you meant by "believes it is Heads." So look at only your first two cases.

If she plays the game 2N times, *and bets on* (i.e., "believes it is") Heads each time, she will wager a total of 3N tokens. She will get N/P tokens back, where P is the probability of Heads. Thus her average gain *per game* is the (N/P)/(2N)=0.5/P tokens. That's their 0.5. By "her loss", they mean the 3N tokens wagered, which averages (3N)/(2N)=1.5 tokens. To break even, we need 0.5/P=1.5, so P=1/3.

The problem is that not everybody believes that this is set up correctly. If you look at individual wagers, instead of individual games, you can use similar techniques to get P=1/2. But imo you have to ignore that some wagers are not independent, so that is wrong. A better conclusion is that wagering is not a good way to approach this problem.

Not many people recall it, but you digress from the original experimental procedure. (You also left out the amnesia drug, but you stated its result). All the original actually says is that SB will be wakened once if the coin lands Heads, and twice if it lands Tails. ("Self-locating belief and the Sleeping Beauty problem", Adam Elga). The two days, and the specifically the order of the wakings on Monday and Tuesday, was how Elga formulated his solution. There is a better way.

- Flip two coins, C1 and C2. C2 will have no bearing on what SB ever knows, it is just used to create the circumstances Elga asks for.
- If either coin shows Tails: wake SB, interview her, and put her back to sleep with amnesia.
- Turn C2 over to show its other face, and repeat that same process; that is, wake SB if either coin is showing Tails, and interview her.
- In the interview, regardless of whether C2 has been turned over, ask SB for her probability/confidence/credence/whatever that C1 is showing Heads.

To formulate her answer, SB knows that the state of the coins was evaluated before waking her. Regardless of previous or subsequent evaluations, there were four equally-likely states for the two coins: {HH, HT, TH, TT}. But since she is awake, she knows that HH is eliminated. In only one of the three equally-likely cases is C1 showing Heads, so the answer is 1/3.

The only issue is whether Elga's solution, which amounts to placing C2 on the table showing Tails instead of flipping it, changes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it makes a little more sense now. But isn't using N/P already using the probability of heads to be 1/2 because otherwise it would need to be 2N/P? And how exactly does your algorithm for your game work?

Comment: It uses correct probability theory, not the rationalization uses to explain wagers. Try it without sleep: In experiment A, I flip C1 and C2 out of your sight. If either shows Tails, I ask for your confidence that C1 landed on Heads; if both are tails, I say "oops." You'd answer 1/3 if you are asked, right? Experiment B works the same way except I turn C2 over after I flip it. You will still say 1/3. This is exactly what I described for SB above, except that she doesn't know if I used experiment A or experiment B. Just that I used one of them, and if I said "oops" she slept through it.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Would you mind updating your answer to better explain the setup for your game, because it's a little confusing to be honest, especially the part where you "repeat the same process". So you're asking her whether it's head on c1 and are only left with 3 options because in the 4th case you wouldn't ask her? And what do you mean by turn over and is she aware of that, is it relevant to the interview/don't interview question?

Comment: I mean you'd technically run into an infinite loop if C1 would be tails, but I think I get your point C2 is just there so that it's once for heads and twice for tails, though in your case she would be always be awake on Tuesday rather than Monday, but as there's nothing that could give her that hint, that should be irrelevant. Though she could only rule out H, H if it were Monday, drawing an initial H, H and be woken up on Tuesday is actually possible, right?

Comment: The process you repeat starts with looking at the coins, not flipping. The point of the procedure is to wake SB once, or twice, depending on C1. Not to start an infinite loop. The point of doing it this way is to make Monday and/or Tuesday irrelevant. The "prior" is the state of the coins when they are examined.

Comment: Monday and Tuesday were also irrelevant in the original as you couldn't distinguish them and as they didn't contribute information, also if you made the "repeat" the next day you could also introduce them. But the "only 3 viable options for being awake" makes a much better argument for a switch from 1/2 to 1/3 despite no new information. Though if you wanted to argue for 1/2 you could point out that the significance of C2 is vastly bigger than that of C1 2/3 vs 1/3 to be precise so that if you're only asking for 1/3 you would likely have to weight the probabilities with that.

Comment: Monday and Tuesday may (thirders) or may not (halfers) require a different probability distribution to describe that day. Even though SB does not know which day it is, in the thirder solution she applies another probability distribution to account for that unknown information (halfers deny that this is valid). In my version, only one probability space is needed, hence the ordering of the awakenings is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd still argue that Mon/Tue are irrelevant and that the actual question is about whether you're awake for the 1st or 2nd time. And while you're still having different options that lead to being waken for the first (TT, TH, HT) or second time (TT, TH, HH) it's true that even that knowledge (whether it's the 1st or 2nd time) would leave you with 3 options and 1/3 for Heads, While in the Mon/Tue the 2nd case would settle it and 1st would leave you with a 50:50. Though in the end the crucial question is what is the objective? Because as shown in the original question  there is ...

Comment: ... an objective benefit to saying tails. Not because it's more likely but because in case it is tails you're asked more questions and thus more questions you're able to flunk or succeed. So if your objective is to answer the interview right more often than yes you should pick tails but you don't have to be within the scenario to know that you also get that from the description of the scenario. While if you're you'd answered randomly or consistent but only 1 answer per run is counted then the probability would be 1/2. So at least Bostrom is wrong for assuming you gained new info, right?

Comment: Sorry obviously the 1st and 2nd time to be waken up and the knowledge about it would also settle it in your case as well. The difference is just that whether the first of second check leads to an interview is irrelevant. Though that was never relevant in the other case either, right?

Comment: There is no subjective difference between the 1st and 2nd wakings in my version. If you do not see this, you do not understand how it differs from the usual version. The “prior” state is not based on how the coins flipped, but on what face was showing when this step of the procedure began. C1 is the same regardless, so the answer to the question is unaffected. The three possible state are {TT, TH, HT}, and in only one is C1 showing Heads.

Comment: You're only awake for a 2nd time if C1 shows tails, that's the same in your version and the original. And in both versions you're unaware of how many times you had been awake or what the coins show, so there's no subjective difference between the 2 or 1 time that SB is awake. Now there are 2 chances to be awake and while they are in sequential order in the original in your case SB could be awake on monday+tuesday, monday or tuesday. So you'd have really no way of telling if it's the first or second just from the "day". But you don't know the day to begin with, so practically it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also sure the 3 possible states that are available to you are TT, TH and HT but you don't know whether it was HT to begin with or wether it started fro HH. So for "Monday" it's HT and for "Tuesday" it would have been HH but either way you'd have no way of telling and both would have the heads for c1 exactly once out of three options.

Comment: You are completely missing the point. The distinction between 1st and 2nd waking only matters when there is a probabilistic difference between them. Try it this way: I'll flip the two coins. If either shows Tails, I'll ask for the probability that C1 shows Heads; but if both show Heads, I'll ask what you want for your birthday. When in fact I ask about C1, what should you say? Does it change if I turn C2 over first? Does what I do if I see HH matter? What if I don't do anything?

Comment: I get that at this point I'm just confused as to what you're trying to tell me with that.

Comment: You keep trying to figure out how I handle, as a random variable, something that I have no need to treat as a random variable. THE ORDER OF THE WAKINGS IS NOT RELEVANT TO ANYTHING. Ignore it. The "decision," made by the experimenters about whether to wake SB, represents information. Because it reduces the sample space from {HH,HT,TH,TT}, which SB knows because she was told the procedure, to {TH,HT,TT}, which SB knows because she is awake now. The order is irrelevant because this applies the same way to any waking.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the order but about how often you have been awake. Whether it's the 1st or 2nd time gives you relevant information whether it's the first or section check or whether they how they are ordered is irrelevant. The original puts unnecessary value on that via mon/tue but essentially it's just about are you awake for the 2nd time or is that the first time that you are awake. Once you are awake you'd no way to tell how often you were awake anyway. And yes if you are awake in your case it must be a choice between TH, HT or TT. But from your setup you'd know that...

Comment: it's always X, H and X,T so if you are awake it could be and at least once actually is due to the value of C2 not C1. How would that knowledge interfere with your credence?

Comment: Whether it is the 1st or 2nd time is order. It's irrelevant. And your Xs aren't independent. Before you were awakened, it could have been HH, HT, TH, or TT. This is true whether you were awakened before, left asleep before, or neither. Since you are awake, you know it isn't HH. This is true whether you were awakened before, left asleep before, neither, or how the coins actually flipped.

Comment: By 2 times I mean 2 times being awake I DO NOT MEAN ANY PARTICULAR ORDER. sry. Like you've essentially 2 possible set of options HH and HT or TH and TT. Now being awake once tells you nothing about what set it is because either of them has you awake with 100% probability at least once and as you can't tell whether it's the first or second time (in a row) that you are awake you can't tell what is more likely. That's essentially the same problem as in the original.

Comment: And by "order" I mean you are concerned with a different waking that may, or may not, have occurred before this one, or could occur after it. Unlike the usual wording, here ALL THAT MATTERS ARE THE CIRCUMSTANCES THAT PERTAIN TO THE CURRENT WAKING. Two coins were examined. When they were examined they could have been HH, HT, TH, or TT. But because SB is awake, she knows that HH is eliminated. Anything that could have happened before the examination, or after SB answers, is completely irrelevant. And yes, it is essentially the same PROBLEM as the original, but it has this unambiguous SOLUTION.

Comment: If you are awake for the 2nd time and aware of it, then you know it's {TT} while if you are awake for the first time it could be one of two sets {{HH, HT}, {TH,TT}}. Now the probability that you are awake once is 100% the probability that you are awake twice is 50%. Or if you compute the probabilities it's 2/3 vs 1/3. Meaning you'd default to assuming it's the 1st time awake and there you have 2 sets of options and both are equally likely to have produced your outcome. Meaning probability for the first set or heads is 1/2. So in other words it's not unambiguous.

Comment: That being said, again, if your goal is to answer the most interviews correctly you should obviously go with tails as you'll get more interviews for tails and thus more interviews right compared to heads. And it's actually 1/3 heads and 2/3 tails. So in that regard this logic actually works. And obviously your version does a better job of exemplifying what the 3 outcomes and that it's independent of the day that you are awake or the order of awake and asleep. Like your monday could be on monday or on tuesday.

Comment: I think you forgot that I staged the original problem differently. There is no difference between the "first" and "second" times that SB might be wakened.

Comment: But there is no difference between the first and second time  being awake in the original either. It will always feel as if you were awake for the first time. Of course using Monday and Tuesday and having a sequential order makes it sound as if that were to be important, but for the person inside the scenario it feels exactly the same way and so the probability is exactly the same. So it's not about the order it's about how often they are awake and that SB can't know that.

Comment: There is a difference, but SB cannot detect it because it is part of the backdrop to her experience. It is this difference that causes the debate between halfers and thirders. Literally, how you meld the two possible backdrops defines you as halfer or thirder. My version does not have different backdrops, so it can be solved unambiguously.

Comment: I mean the explanation for the thirder position of Elga as sketched on Wikipedia to me makes the mistake that P(Tue|T) = P(Mon|T) = 1/4, i.e. 1/2 for the tails and 1/2 for the day. But P(T|Mon) = P(H|Mon) = 1/3, i.e. 2/3 for Monday and 1/2 for the coin. So P(T|Mon) is not the same as P(Mon|T). Though you could rephrase it as your example and get rid of that problem. Also I think I know what you meant be different probability space. For Elga it's either Monday and the choice between H/T or Tails and the choice between Mon/Tue. In your case Mon has 3 options  but tails still only has 2, right?

Comment: In Elga's solution, Pr(Mon&T)=Pr(Tue&T)=1/4. From that, we can get Pr(Mon|T) = Pr(Mon&T)/Pr(T) = (1/4)/(1/2) = 1/2. Elga interprets the question to be Pr(H|[Mon&H or Mon&H or Tue&H) = (1/4)/(1/4+1/4+1/4 = 1/3.

Comment: "Pr(H|[Mon&H or Mon&H or Tue&H) = (1/4)/(1/4+1/4+1/4 = 1/3" How does that work? I mean Mon&H appears twice and Tue&H has a probability of 0. I get the thirder version but that makes no sense, does it?